# Replacing a word in a file

Tags: python, file, file-handling

```
badcontent = []
filebadword = "badwords.txt"
with open(filebadword, 'r') as read_file:
  badcontent = read_file.readlines()

goodcontent = []
filegoodword = "goodword.txt"
with open(filegoodword, 'r') as read_file:
  goodcontent = read_file.readlines()


msgfile = "msg.txt"
file = open(msgfile, "r")
for word in file:
  if word in badcontent:
    file = file.write(word.replace([badcontent],[goodconent]))
    print(file.readline())
    file.close()
  elif():
    print(file.readline())
    file.close()
```

I want to try replace a 'inappropriate' word in the text msg file with a friendly word.

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: how can I check if a word in msg.txt is in the array badconent and if it is, how to replace it with a word from goodcontent

Comment: the msg.txt file still has the exact same words

Comment: @MEdwin the code is NOT ok, very obviously. Actually it doesn't even compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has `string.replace(old, new)`-method. You are trying now to replace one word with a list and this will result in an error. Here is an example how you should go through whole text:

```
from random import randint

with open("text_msg_file.txt", 'rb') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Text file containing bad words, assume only one word/line
with open("badcontent.txt", 'rb') as f:
    badcontent = f.readlines()

# Text file containing good words, assume only one word/line
with open("goodcontent.txt", 'rb') as f:
    goodcontent = f.readlines()

# Strip new line character from words
lines = [word.strip("\n") for word in lines]
badcontent = [word.strip("\n") for word in badcontent]
goodcontent = [word.strip("\n") for word in goodcontent]

for i in range(len(lines)):
    line = lines[i]
    # List of words on single line. Line splitted from whitespaces
    words = line.split(" ")
    # Loop through all words
    for j in range(len(words)):
        # Get random integer for index
        index = randint(0, len(goodcontent))
        if words[j] in badcontent:
            # Replace bad word with a good word
            words[j] = goodcontent[index]
    # Join all words from a list into a string
    line = " ".join(words)
    # Put string back to list of lines
    lines[i] = line
# Join all lines back into one single text
new_text = "\n".join(lines)
with open("new_msg.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(new_text)
```

This writes text with replaced words into file `new_msg.txt`. With Python 2.7 use `'rb'` and `'wb'` for `open`-statements to enable opening in binary mode, so the code is more robust. With Python 3 use only `'r'` and `'w'` for `open`-statements.

Comment: @J.Peggy Edited my answer. I added stripping new lines from lines. It works when I tested it

Comment: keep on getting this error 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    lines = [word.strip("\n") for word in lines]
  File "main.py", line 15, in <listcomp>
    lines = [word.strip("\n") for word in lines]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @J.Peggy Which Python version you have? I tested this with 2.7. If you are using Python3 just change all `rb` and `wb` to `r` and `w`

Comment: @J.Peggy If this got your problem solved, please mark this answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't understand if in your Bad and Good file they are present only a parameter.
If you have not a dictionary you cant make a correction.

```
dictionary={}
dictionary['****']='#######'
dictionary['inappropriate_word']='good'

new_file=''
for line in file:
    for word in line:
        if word in dictionary:
            new_file+=dictionary[word]
        else:
            new_file+=word
        new_file+=" "
    new_file+="\n"
```

or

```
dictionary={}
dictionary['****']='#######'
dictionary['inappropriate_word']='good'

l=open(file,"r").read()
for i in dictionary:
    l.replace(i,dictionary[i])
o=open("fileoutput.txt","w")
o.write(l)
o.close()
```

if you have 2 file with words you can import and stock the information in a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Tried on text (not real data):

```
import shelve

class TextArgsCode:
    def __init__(self, function_codetext, text, programfile): #text = 'define'; replace by function_codetext[text]
        self.text = text
        self.function_codetext = function_codetext
        self.textfile = open(programfile, 'r').read()
        self.textfilewrite = open(programfile+'write.py', 'w')

    
    def textcode_newtext(self):
        for text in self.textfile.split('\n'):
            textwrite = text.replace(self.text, self.function_codetext[self.text])
            if len(textwrite) > 0:
              textwrite = '\n'+textwrite
              self.textfilewrite.write(textwrite)

            else:
              text = '\n'+text
              self.textfilewrite.write(text)
            
        self.textfilewrite.close()  
        return(None)
          





if __name__ == '__main__':
    textargsdata = shelve.open('sqldb.db')
    textargsdata = textargsdata['data']
    textargscode = TextArgsCode(textargsdata, 'define', 'test.py') #replace self.text = 'define' in test.py'
    textargscode.textcode()
```

Comment: From personal project – https://gitlab.com/emmanuelnsanga/speech-text-programming-macro-conversion